# Memory Error in Scikit Learn: Nystroem

Tags: python, windows, cygwin, scikit-learn

I am using scikit learn for Nystroem approximation. The  main code is :

```
feature_map_fourier = RBFSampler(gamma=0.5, random_state=1)
feature_map_nystroem = Nystroem(gamma=0.5, random_state=1)
fourier_approx_svm = pipeline.Pipeline([("feature_map", feature_map_fourier),
                                        ("svm", svm.LinearSVC(C=4))])
nystroem_approx_svm = pipeline.Pipeline([("feature_map", feature_map_nystroem),
                                        ("svm", svm.LinearSVC(C=4))])
# fit and predict using linear and kernel svm:
sample_sizes = np.arange(1,20)
print sample_sizes
fourier_scores = []
nystroem_scores = []
fourier_times = []
nystroem_times = []
for D in sample_sizes:
    avgtime = 0.0
    avgscore = 0.0
    avgftime = 0.0
    avgfscore = 0.0
    ns = []
    fs = []
    for i in range(0, 10):
    feature_map_fourier = RBFSampler(gamma=0.5, random_state=i) 
        feature_map_nystroem = Nystroem(gamma=0.5, random_state=i)
        fourier_approx_svm = pipeline.Pipeline([("feature_map", feature_map_fourier),
                                        ("svm", svm.LinearSVC(C=1))])
        nystroem_approx_svm = pipeline.Pipeline([("feature_map", feature_map_nystroem),("svm", svm.LinearSVC(C=1))])
    nystroem_approx_svm.set_params(feature_map__n_components=D)
        nystroem_approx_svm.fit(data_train, targets_train)
        fourier_approx_svm.set_params(feature_map__n_components=D)
        fourier_approx_svm.fit(data_train, targets_train)
        start = time()
        fourier_score = fourier_approx_svm.score(data_test, targets_test)
        t = time() - start

        avgftime += t
        avgfscore += fourier_score     
        start = time()
        nystroem_score = nystroem_approx_svm.score(data_test, targets_test)
        t = time() - start
        avgtime +=  t
        avgscore += nystroem_score
        ns.append(avgscore)
        fs.append(avgfscore)
    print 'Nstrrom '+str(np.std(ns))
    print 'fs '+str(np.std(ns))    
    nystroem_times.append(avgtime/10.0)
    nystroem_scores.append(avgscore/10.0)
    fourier_times.append(avgftime/10.0)
    fourier_scores.append(avgfscore/10.0)
```

i am getting following error while trying to run this code.

```
C:\Users\t-sujain\Documents\LDKL BaseLine\Nystreom>forestNormalized_kernel_appro
x.py
522910
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\t-sujain\Documents\LDKL BaseLine\Nystreom\forestNormalized_kern
el_approx.py", line 70, in <module>
    nystroem_approx_svm.fit(data_train, targets_train)
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 126, in fit
    Xt, fit_params = self._pre_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 116, in _pre_tr
ansform
    Xt = transform.fit_transform(Xt, y, **fit_params_steps[name])
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 364, in fit_transfo
rm
    return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\kernel_approximation.py", line 470
, in transform
    gamma=self.gamma)
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 808, in
 pairwise_kernels
    return func(X, Y, **kwds)
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 345, in
 rbf_kernel
    K = euclidean_distances(X, Y, squared=True)
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 148, in
 euclidean_distances
    XX = X.multiply(X).sum(axis=1)
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 251, in
multiply
    return self._binopt(other,'_elmul_')
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 676, in
_binopt
    data    = np.empty(maxnnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype,other.dtype))
MemoryError
```

i am using cygbin and a system with 100GB of RAM, so there is no chance that the system is getting out of memory. Can some one please help me in this?

Comment: Well obviously your system is running out of memory. It might be a problem in the sklearn implementation of the `transform` method. What is the shape of your data `(n_samples, n_features)`? Apparently you left `n_components` to the default value of 100. Is that right?

Comment: Actually I misread the code. Can you print the value of `D`, the number of components before the program crashes?

Comment: Also what is the version of scikit-learn you are using?

Comment: Can you try to build the master branch of scikit-learn? I think @larsmans recently checked in some optimization for the sparse data case that might fix your problem.

Comment: yes i can print the value of D.

Comment: i am using scikit-learn 0.13. i cant build as i am using windows binaries.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the discussion in the comments: this crash results from a quadratic over-allocation that happens in the transform method when passing sparse data as input. It has been fixed in the master branch after the 0.14.1 release.

Also note: using the RBF kernel on high-dimensional sparse input might not be very beneficial. Usually the sparse matrix representation is used for sparse high-dimensional data such as bag of words features for text documents. For such data the linear kernel is often as good or better as non-linear kernels hence the `Nystroem` method might be useless in this case.

Comment: even the 0.14.1 release didn't solves this problem. this was the problem with the 32 bit version. with 64 bit version, these problem is solved.

Comment: It probably means that you are using 4GB+ memory then. You can have a look at [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) to pinpoint the culprit if you are interested.